# Macro to delete duplicate cells in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying pull data from workbook1 to workbook2. the idea is that the data is copied to the correct place in the second workbook. if the data is already in the spreadsheet but in the wrong row, (ie WIP instead of Paid), i then want to clear the contents of that row (as the new data has been inputted). I've tried to create a code for this, but i either get error 400 or  a runtime error (1004).

I've managed to get the first part of the code working, which pulls the data from workbook1 to the correct area of workbook2, but i can't get the code to delete the old data.

I think the error lies with comparing the value of the cells from workbook1 to workbook2 after the data was copied over.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'insert variables as objects
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range, rga As Range, rgc As Range

'set variables
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Workbook2")
Set wsa = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = wsa.Range("B12")
Set rga = wsa.Range("B124")
Set rgc = wsa.Range("B125")

'Identifies the next available Row
rg.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

'Pastes Data
ActiveSheet.Paste

If ActiveCell = rga Then
   rga.Resize("1, 9").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   ElseIf ActiveCell = rgc Then
   rgc.Resize("1, 9").Select
   Selection.ClearContents
   End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: I don't think you require quotes around the resize numbers

Comment: You could improve your variable naming, for example adding source/target 'tag' to them, eg 'wbFrom' and 'wbTo' etc. Try to use ranges variables instead of `activesheet` and `Selection`, it better communicates your intentions.

Comment: @Davesexcel it doesn't tell me the line unfortunately, just a message box saying 'error 400' or a runtime error.

Comment: @leosch how would i use range variables in that way?

Comment: @EthanBrown Use it like this: `rga.Resize(1,9).ClearContents` instead of selecting it first, then clear the content of the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
'insert variables as objects
Dim wb As Workbook, wsa As Worksheet
Dim rg As Range, rga As Range, rgc As Range

'set variables
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("Workbook2")
Set wsa = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rg = wsa.Range("B12").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set rga = wsa.Range("B124")
Set rgc = wsa.Range("B125")

wsa.Paste Destination:=rg

Select Case rg.Value
    Case rga.Value: rga.Resize(1, 9).ClearContents
    Case rgc.Value: rgc.Resize(1, 9).ClearContents
End Select
```

As noted in the comments above - typically you don't need to Select/Activate objects before working with them: that's an artifact of the macro recorder.